# drawing a polygon of your choice for a set of numbers given by the user

Tags: java, eclipse, polygon

```
package package13;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Polygon extends JApplet {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int i,j;        

        int poly[]=new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter 5 pairs of coordinates for the polygon:");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        for (i=0;i<poly.length;i++) {
            poly[i]=scan.nextInt();
        }
        for (j=0;j<poly.length;j++) {
            System.out.print(" "+poly[j]);
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);
        resize(500,500);
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    }   
}
```

I am trying to draw a polygon of the users choice for a set of numbers given by the user.
Any help with this?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Failing to plan is planning to fail. A pen and paper is what got civilizations through time, code is just a distraction from the problem at hand.

Comment: if you haven't done so already see [`Polygon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) and [`Graphics2D.draw(Shape)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw(java.awt.Shape)) which will make drawing simpler

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing input paradigms (console and GUI).

Most GUI's are event driven environments, something happens, you respond to it.

This is made even worse by the fact that you're using an Applet, as it is even less likely that the user will have any kind of console to use.

You're also mixing application paradigms (Applet and `main`).

Start by...

- Reading through [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).
- Use a `JFrame` as your top level container, it has less issues the applet and will make your life simpler
- Create a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and place your custom painting there.
- Don't call methods that might change the state of the UI from within any paint method
- Reading through [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)